# Существует ли аналог TASM?

Tags: ассемблер

В ВУЗе требуют сдавать программы, написанные в TASM.
Но проблема в его древности, в следствии чего:
1)На ОС х64 он не работает и требуется использовать DOSBOX
2)Приходится постоянно использовать команды, что бы скомпилировать программу
3)Зачастую при использовании DOSBOX, TASM начинает глючить.

Есть ли какие-то современные аналоги TASM с идентичным синтаксисом, но более приятной средой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно именно с идентичным синтаксисом, т.е. старый добрый TASM, то остается только попытаться сделать с ним работу приятнее.

Есть проект [Tasm for Windows 7/8/8.1/9 32bit & 64bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tasmforwindows/), можно посмотреть на него.

Есть проект [TASM Visual](http://gri-software.ru/tasmvisual.html) , небольшая IDE (по сути, только подсветка синтаксиса), сделана на .NET, успешно компилирует и запускает на Windows 8 64-bit.

Как еще один вариант, создать виртуальную машину с 32-битной ОС и поставить туда обычный TASM, к нему любой удобный редактор для asm-файлов.

Answer (score 1):

В Linux есть `nasm` и `as`/`gas`.

Различаются они тем, что поддерживают Intel и AT&T синтаксис соответственно (хотя gas можно переключать на Intel-синтаксис при желании) (кроме того есть ещё одно, более существенное отличие: `nasm` это полноценный ассемблер, а `gas` это бэкенд для GCC; но не будем сейчас углубляться).

Intel-код выглядит так:

```
section .data
    hello:     db 'Hello world!',10    ; 'Hello world!' plus a linefeed character
    helloLen:  equ $-hello             ; Length of the 'Hello world!' string
                                       ; (I'll explain soon)

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax,4            ; The system call for write (sys_write)
    mov ebx,1            ; File descriptor 1 - standard output
    mov ecx,hello        ; Put the offset of hello in ecx
    mov edx,helloLen     ; helloLen is a constant, so we don't need to say
                         ;  mov edx,[helloLen] to get it's actual value
    int 80h              ; Call the kernel

    mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
    int 80h
```

Собрать и слинковать:

```
nasm -f elf hello.asm
ld -s -o hello hello.o
```

AT&T-синтаксис отличается обилием знаков % на каждом шагу.

Например, сравните Intel-синтаксис:

```
movb    %bl,%al
movw    %bx,%ax
movl    %ebx,%eax
movl    (%ebx),%eax
```

и AT&T-синтаксис:

```
mov al,bl
mov ax,bx
mov eax,ebx
mov eax, dword ptr [ebx]
```

Что касается среды разработки, то вы можете использовать простой редактор, например Vim или Emacs (ну, Emacs это не совсем простой редактор).
В Emacs у вас даже есть специальный asm-режим, который обеспечивается модулем
`nasm-mode.el`.

Дополнительная информация:

- [Introduction to Linux Intel Assembly Language](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/50/LinuxAssembly.html) (англ.)

Comment: +1, но стоит заметить, что программирование всего, что выходит за рамки простого доступа к регистрам, сильно отличается. Никакого `int 21h`, никакой таблицы прерываний, никаких COM-файлов с PSP.

Comment: @VladD: В смысле в Linux и в DOS?

Comment: Угу. Если человеку нужен TASM, его лабораторные наверняка заканчиваются на [`mov ah, 4Ch / int 21h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2974.htm).

Comment: @VladD: Посмотрим, многое зависит от преподавателя. В действительности всё же ассемблер это одно, а работа с операционной системой это другое. Довольно многие вещи можно сделать вообще не обращаясь к операционной системе, тогда разница будет сравнительно маленькая

Answer (score 1):

В качестве среды можно попробовать [SASM](http://dman95.github.io/SASM/) (понимает NASM, MASM, GAS и FASM).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Среда приятная, но чистого TASM кода не понимает=(

Comment: Так сам по себе TASM уже в глубоком прошлом :) Ну или вот, сам не пробовал: http://sourceforge.net/projects/guitasm8086/

Comment: Да, но как не печально, его все еще преподают=(

Comment: sourceforge.net/projects/guitasm8086 Вроде компилит, но нет дебаггера или я его не нашел=(